# ImagePicker set crop area size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

Default ImagePicker crop area is square (like image)

But I want to set it to be a rectangle, and I can get a rectangle image to use

Is there a easy way to set it?

I know [GKImagePicker](https://github.com/gekitz/GKImagePicker) is very powerful but I don't know why image that below the crop area can't be scroll up.

thanks in advance

[image]

======edit for code=====

```
 - (BOOL)startMediaBrowserFromViewController: (UIViewController*) controller
                               usingDelegate: (id<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>) delegate
                                        type: (int)type_{

if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
      UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum] == NO)
    || (delegate == nil)
    || (controller == nil))
    return NO;

UIImagePickerController *mediaUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
mediaUI.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeImage, nil];

if (type_ == 0)
{
    mediaUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
}
else
{
    mediaUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
}

mediaUI.allowsEditing = YES;
mediaUI.delegate = delegate;

[controller presentModalViewController: mediaUI animated: NO];
return YES;
}
```

if I can get rectangle image, I can resize it in

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
NSLog(@"imagePickerControllerDone");

UIImage *image = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:
                              UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
CGSize size = image.size;
image = [ImageManager reSizeImage:image toSize:CGSizeMake(1000, 370)];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    self.carPhoto.image = image;
    photoFlag = YES;
}];
}
```

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: It's how it works and can't be changed, the only way if to create your own crop UI and logic